# Can fruitstrap run with Xcode v5.0.1 OSX v10.8.5 on iOS7 (iPad 4)?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios7

I used to success to install fruitstrap on OSX v10.8.5, with Xcode v4.6.3. That means I can run app on **iPad2** through cmd line.

Now I turn to another machine, with OSX v10.8.5, **Xcode v5.0.1** and **iPad4 (iOS 7)**. Firstly, I install provistion profile, and I can run a project success on iPad4 (iOS 7) with Xcode. Then, I try to install fruitstrap in the same step(with different IOS_SDK in Makefile). But I got output like this:

```
*------ Install phase ------
[....] Waiting for iOS device to be connected
[  0%] Found device (c97b56bd2b84138a50a95ab3edb518eb79fff5b1), beginning install
[  5%] Copying demo.app/ to device
[  8%] Copying demo.app//_CodeSignature to device
[ 12%] Copying demo.app//_CodeSignature/CodeResources to device
[ 16%] Copying demo.app//demo to device
[ 42%] Copying demo.app//Info.plist to device
[ 46%] Copying demo.app//ResourceRules.plist to device
[ 52%] CreatingStagingDirectory
[ 57%] ExtractingPackage
[ 60%] InspectingPackage
[ 60%] TakingInstallLock
[ 65%] PreflightingApplication
AMDeviceInstallApplication failed: -402653028*
```

At the same time, I can see output from Xcode console of iPad device:

```
*Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[115] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[115] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder (null)
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad installd[62] <Notice>: 0x243000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/demo.app" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad installd[62] <Notice>: 0x243000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app demo
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad installd[62] <Error>: 0x243000 check_can_install: Apps must have a CFBundleVersion declared as a string in their Info.plist, but demo does not. Failing installation.
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad installd[62] <Error>: 0x243000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[115] <Error>: 0x305000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[115] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad mobile_installation_proxy[115] <Error>: 0x305000 handle_install: Installation failed: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x14d14f30 {Error=MissingBundleVersion}
Nov 21 04:07:44 iPad installd[62] <Error>: 0x243000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed*
```

I wonder if there are some compatibility problems with these three tools/devices?

- Xcode v5.0.1
- iPad4 (iOS 7)
- OSX v10.8.5

Answer (score 4):

Fruitstrap itself isn't being maintained and doesn't work with Xcode 5 or iOS 7. You might want to check out one of these alternatives. ios-deploy, in particular, is a fork of fruitstrap that adds basic support:

- https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
- https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice
- https://github.com/robovm/robovm

Comment: When targeting the simulator rather than device, https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim works great.